# For loops for nested variables within function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, montecarlo

I would like to iterate through vectors of values and calculate something for every value while being within a function environment in R. For example:

```
# I have costs for 3 companies
c <- c(10, 20, 30)
# I have the same revenue across all 3 
r <- 100
#  I want to obtain the profits for all 3 within one variable
result <- list()

# I could do this in a for loop
for(i in 1:3){
    result[i] <- r - c[i]
}
```

Now lets assume I have a model that is very long and I define everything as a function which is to be solved with various random draws for the costs.

```
# Random draws
n  <- 1000
r  <- rnorm(n, mean = 100,  sd = 10)
c1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 10,  sd = 1)
c2 <- rnorm(n, mean = 20,  sd = 2)
c3 <- rnorm(n, mean = 30,  sd = 3)
X  <- data.frame(r, c1, c2, c3)

fun <- function(x){
       r  <- x[1]
       c  <- c(x[2], x[3], x[4])

       for(i in 1:3){
           result[i] <- r - c[i]
       }
  return(result)
}
```

I could then evaluate the result for all draws by iterating through the rows of randomly sampled input data.

```
for(j in 1:n){
  x <- X[j,]
  y <- fun(x)
}
```

In this example, the output variable y would entail the nested result variable which comprises of the results for all 3 companies. However, my line of thinking results in an error and I think it has to do with the fact that I try to return a nested variable? Hence my question how you guys would approach something like this.

Comment: You should not use `c` as an object name.

Comment: Well thanks for the information I guess.

Comment: Sorry, an explanation: `c`, as well as quite a list of other letters or words, is a base R function. One should avoid using the names of base functions for object naming. Regarding your question: At least the example you gave could be solved by vectorized functions (example: `x <- r - c` returns the same as `for(i in 1:3){x[i] <- r - c[i]}`. In many situations, R is capable of operating with vectors directly without the need for a loop.

Comment: `t(apply(X, 1, function(x) x[1] - x[2:4]))`

Comment: I did not think of not using c. I tried to make this example as easy as possible because usually I do not obtain any relevant answer on this website but rather comments of complains regarding formatting or what the desired result should look like. Hence, I went for c like cost and made the example as easy as possible. The actual model does not have c as an object. However, I have objects that are lists of lists which entail matrices. This made the monte carlo implementation weirdly difficult

Comment: You could try to store the results in a list. Somewhere before the for loop you define results = list() and within the loop you add each element to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest rethinking your coding approach. This is a very un-R-like way of doing things.

For example, the first `for` loop can be written much more succinctly as

```
x <- c(10, 20, 30)
r <- 100
result <- lapply(-x, `+`, r)
```

Then `fun` becomes something like

```
fun <- function(x) lapply(-x[-1], `+`, x[1])
```

To then operate over the rows of a `data.frame` (which is what you seem to do in the last step), you can use something like

```
apply(X, 1, fun)
```

where the `MARGIN = 1` argument in `apply` ensures that you are applying a function per row (as opposed to per column).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am new to coding in general and in particular to R. I am certain that there are more computationally efficient means of writing it. Do you have any recommendations in line with the bad way of doing it, as I do not have time to rewrite the entire model

Comment: The for-loop (and your `lapply` example) could also be written as `result <- as.list(r - x)`.

Comment: @Kevin It seems that in your example you can replace nearly all `for` loops with `lapply`/`sapply`s. I would say that familiarising yourself with the `*apply` family of functions is a one of the key components when learning R. They offer elegant (and fast) ways to operate over the elements of a `list` (or `vector`, `data.frame`, etc.). Under the hood they are nothing but optimised loops.

Comment: @MauritsEvers okay, I will do so. Will this resolve the issue of returning vector objects from functions or just make the code run faster?

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "returning vector objects". `lapply` returns a `list`. `sapply` does the same as `lapply` but tries to simplify the output to give a vector, `matrix` or `array`. In R storing objects in `list`s is very efficient, as you can subsequently operate on its elements using the same `*apply` methods. It will also be faster than running the `for` loops from your examples, where you dynamically grow a `list` (in R, you should *always* avoid doing that).

Comment: @Kevin [continued] If you must use an explicit `for` loop, always pre-allocate the object with the right dimensions. Then replace entries in the loop. Growing a `list` dynamically inside a loop is a very (probably the most) inefficient way in R. But I recommend familiarising yourself with `*apply` as this is a big part of R's idiosyncratic way of applying functions to objects in a vectorised way.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thank you very much, I am reading into it right now. I wish one of my supervisors would have told me this before I wrote the entire model as for loop after for loop and then wondering why it takes confusingly long to compute. I am afraid changing the model to work exclusively with apply will take me a week or two, but I guess it is worth it. All i came for was to obtain insight how to conduct my sensitivity analysis and I leave sad and concerned :D

Comment: @Kevin Once you get the hang of R's way of `*apply`ing functions it will make things *a lot* easier (and neater and faster). So I would say it'd be time well spent.  It will also make things a lot easier further down the track if/when you move towards the `tidyverse`/`purrr` way of working with and on data. No need to be sad or concerned;-) To speed up things without changing everything, consider pre-allocating the `list`s before you run the loop. So to illustrate, instead of creating an empty list `result <- list()` consider `result <- replicate(3, 0, simplify = F)`.

Comment: @Kevin [continued] This will create a `list` with three 0 elements. These elements will then get replaced inside the `for` loop. That would speed things up (a little). Do something similar for the biggest `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using your function and a for loop:

```r
# Random draws
n  <- 1000
r  <- rnorm(n, mean = 100,  sd = 10)
c1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 10,  sd = 1)
c2 <- rnorm(n, mean = 20,  sd = 2)
c3 <- rnorm(n, mean = 30,  sd = 3)
X  <- data.frame(r, c1, c2, c3)

result <- list()

fun <- function(x){
  r  <- x[[1]]
  c  <- c(x[[2]], x[[3]], x[[4]])

  for(i in 1:3){
    result[i] <- r - c[i]
  }
  return(result)
}

# Create a list to store results 
profits <- rep(rep(list(1:3)),nrow(X))

# Loop throuhg each row of dataframe and store in profits.
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){

  profits_temp <- 
    fun(list(X[i,"r"],X[i,"c1"],X[i,"c2"],X[i,"c3"]))

  for(j in 1:3)
    profits[[i]][[j]] <- profits_temp[[j]]

  }

# Eye results
profits[[1]]
#> [1] 93.23594 81.25731 70.27699

profits[[2]]
#> [1] 80.50516 69.27517 63.36439
```